# Water washable resin safety

Tags: resin, safety

I recently spilled waste water from my resin printing onto a fabric cooler. The water was in a container I was using to cure leftover resin from cleaning finished prints by leaving it in the sun for a while. So there was an unknown amount of uncured resin in it after I had left it out for a few hours.

Is it likely that the cooler is permanently contaminated or should I be able to wash it and use it again? It isn't a really expensive one but also not really something I wanted to replace yet.

Comment: "after I had left it out for a few hours" - Are we talking 3 hours or 5 hours? More? I know the basics of resin printing but I would imagine that the longer it was left out in the sun, the more resin would have cured.

Comment: we can say 5 hours but I don't really know exactly how long it was out at the time when I spilled it. I had brought it back in due to rain and wind incoming and left it to try to completely evaporate the water once the sun came back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calling the cooler a loss.  I don't know what that resin will do embedded in the fabric of the cooler and I don't really want to drink poison when I am out on the beach or develop some sort of sensitivity from it. Ended up getting a new cooler as a gift so it all evened out.